# $A^{1/2}$ commutes with $B^{1/2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, unbounded-operators

Let $A,B$ be two positive (possibly unbounded) closed operator on a Hilbert space with $AB=BA$. Do we have $A^{1/2}$ commutes with $B^{1/2}$?

I know it is true for bounded operators but I am not sure for unbounded case.

Comment: Do you want positive operators to be self-adjoint or just symmetric? If symmetric, then how do you want to define $A^{1/2}$? In the case of self-adjointess two operators commuting means there is a common root $C$ and functions $f,g$ so that $A=f(C), B=g(C)$. With the spectral calculus you can find that $f(C)^{1/2}$ and $g(C)^{1/2}$ commute.

Comment: It turns out that symmetric positive operators have self-adjoint extensions, at [least this webpage says so](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Positive_operator).